# Eloquent class not found

Tags: php, eloquent

Fairly new to eloquent, and trying to echo some test users but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Social\php\user-query.php on line 3
```

Any idea why it's not working ?

php/user-query.php:

```
<?php
include 'db-connection.php';
$user = User::all();
foreach($user as $u) {
  echo $u['id'];
}
?>
```

php/User.php:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

class User extends Model
{
  public $table = "user";
  protected $fillable = ['id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There was nothing wrong with the code, I just used

```
composer dump-autoload
```

in CMD and it worked fine :)

Comment: It's worked fine on me, if you got message "Permission Denied" just use sudo in Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Inside your file php/user-query.php add this at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\User;
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
```

You need to tell to php where to find the class User to use It

Comment: This assumes a front controller or you need to require the path to the autoloader in user-query.php

Comment: then I get the error:

    Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\User' not found in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Social\php\user-query.php on line 6

Comment: You need to point to your User class, I thought that was in that path